# Django: aggregate django fields to avoid N + 1 problem

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I have 3 tables/classes that are relevant to each other:

- CourseStudent - represents Student signed up to the course
- Presence - represents the attendance list of the CourseStudent
- CourseStudentPayment - represents the payments list for CourseStudent

In the code it looks like this:

```
class CourseStudentPayment(models.Model):
    course_student = models.ForeignKey(
        "CourseStudent",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="course_student_payments",
    )
    start_date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    # other fields: price, currency, etc
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def lessons_complete(self) -> int:
        return (
            Presence.objects.filter(
                course_student=self.course_student,
            )
            .filter(date__gte=self.start_date)
            .count()
        )

class Presence(models.Model):
    course_student = models.ForeignKey("CourseStudent", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    # some other fields


class CourseStudent(models.Model):
   # some course-related information
   student = models.CharField(...)

   def last_payment(self) -> CourseStudentPayment:
        return CourseStudentPayment.objects.filter(course_student=self).order_by("-start_date").first()
```

So `lessons_complete` function calculates the number of the attendances since the payment date. Both `CourseStudentPayment` and `Presence` objects have `CourseStudent` pk.

I want to render a list of payments for the students with lessons_complete in an efficient way. The dumb solution would be:

- get list of payments. `course_payments = CourseStudentPayment.objects.all()`
- for each payment I call lessons_complete.

This solution creates N+1 problem, where for each payment I do Presence lookup.

In SQL I would just join two tables (pseudocode):

```
SELECT csp.*, count(p.id) from CourseStudentPayment csp
JOIN Presence p ON scp.course_student_id = p.course_student_id
WHERE p.date > csp.start_date
```

Is it possible to aggregate Presence table results and use within CourseStudentPayment rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F

course_payments = CourseStudentPayment.objects.filter(
    course_student__presence__date__gt=F('start_date')
).annotate(presence_count=Count('course_student__presence'))
```

The `CourseStudentPayment` objects will have an extra attribute `.presence_count` with the number of `Presence`s after the `start_date` of the `CourseStudentPayment` object.

This will however leave out `CourseStudentPayment`s without any `Presence`, you can include these with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F

course_payments = CourseStudentPayment.objects.annotate(
    presence_count=Count(
        'course_student__presence',
        filter=Q(course_student__presence__date__gt=F('start_date')),
    )
)
```

Comment: Wow, that's great! I printed raw SQL of each query to understand the difference, on the second case it does LEFT OUTER JOIN on `Presence` table, that's why it includes `CourseStudentPayment`s without any `Presence`s.

Thank you!